# AWS Glue Terraform - Specify map as an input argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, aws-glue

Is there anyway to specify map/json structure as an input argument for aws glue job? I'm doing it in this way in terraform:

```
glue_jobs =[
 {
   name ="SampleGlueJob"
  
   default_arguments ={
    "--dateConversion"={
     "columns"=["column_1"]
     "dateFormat"="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"}
      }
   }
]
```

but terrform apply step is failing with exception `Inconsistent conditional result types`